# Execute command on windows client from windows server

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows

how can we execute command on CMD or power shell windows clients from a windows server or admin domain on network

we are using windows server 2016 for active directory
and all users have windows 10

we want to send "gpresult /r" and "gpupdate" command on clients

Answer (score 0):

To run commands remotely, you can use either Windows Remote Shell (WinRs) or PowerShell Remoting.  However, gpresult commonly fails to execute properly under these circumstances and should not be considered reliable. Gpupdate may be run, but should be used with `/target:computer` switch.   Both WinRs/PSRemoting require port tcp/5985 or tcp/5986 (for TLS) for network communication, use the same underlying technology, and is a native tool and not an external binary.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/winrs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/08-powershell-remoting?view=powershell-7.3